# How to stop contact form 7 reload the page after submit without include wp_head in header file?

Tags: wordpress

I am facing issue that, contact form 7 load the page after submit.I have made separate header without WP_head include.

I am using like in separate template file:

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="6039" title="Hire us pop up form"]'); ?>
```

Please help.

Comment: Please, add your code.

Comment: which code I should add?

Comment: In contact for 7 you are having additional setting tab. Have you write any jquery code of redirection. Please check that and let me know.

Comment: can you please tell me that code?

Comment: And I donot want the redirection, I just want to stop reload form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding these scripts in my custom header file

```
    <script>

    jvcf7_loading_url= "#/wp-
    content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif";
    jvcf7_invalid_field_design = "theme_1";
    jvcf7_show_label_error = "errorMsgshow";

   </script>

   <script type='text/javascript' src='https:#/wp-
   content/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-
   7/js/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>

   <script>
   /* <![CDATA[ */
   var wpcf7 = {"apiSettings":
   {"root":"http:\/\/#\/wp-
   json\/","namespace":"contact-form-7\/v1"},"recaptcha":{"messages":
   {"empty":"Please verify that you are not a robot."}}};
   /* ]]> */
   </script>

   <script type='text/javascript' src='#/wp-
   content/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-
   7/js/jquery.jvcf7_validation.js'></script>
```

Comment: Nice to get know, you found solution. Remember to mark your answer, as correct ;)

Comment: Upvote is for input to question/answer. Not solving itself. Maybe another time :)

Comment: Fine...@timiTao